# 'snap list' shows 3 installed packages, can I still purge snapd on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, snap, purge

I found with a search machine [Safe to remove snap on Ubuntu Server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539952/safe-to-remove-snap-on-ubuntu-server). In this posting his `snap list` output is empty. No installed packages.

At me the list not empty..

version, Raspberry Pi 4 hardware (64bit image):

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
```

snap info

```
snap list
Name    Version    Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core    16-2.45.1  9441   latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18  20200427   1753   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
lxd     4.2        15763  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
```

What is this? What are `core`, `core18` and `lxd`? Is it needed?

Is it still safe to do those cleanup commands?

```
sudo apt purge snapd
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

`lxd` is a container manager, the other two are the core runtime environment for `snapd` and the base snap, originally for Ubuntu 18.04.

You can remove them the way you suggested without issues.